# Cakephp core XML class String could not be parsed as XML

Tags: php, xml, cakephp

I've tried below query and used Cake's core XML class but I get String could not be parsed as XML error...

```
$output = $this->Job->query("
            SELECT job.id, job.title, organisation.name, jobsboard.name
            FROM job
            LEFT JOIN portfolio_job_category pjc ON pjc.job_id = job.id
            LEFT JOIN category c ON c.id = pjc.category_id
            LEFT JOIN organisation ON organisation.id = job.organisation_id
            LEFT JOIN portfolio jobsboard ON jobsboard.id = pjc.portfolio_id
            WHERE job.end_date >= DATE( NOW( ) ) 
            AND pjc.portfolio_id = $portfolio
            ORDER BY c.id DESC
            ");
$jobs['jobs_feed'] = $output;
$jobs = Xml::fromArray($jobs);
$jobs = $jobs->asXML();
```

Below is my array output from model's custom query.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [job] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 38459
                    [title] => UTS: Engineering Research Scholarships in Petroleum Remediation
                )

            [organisation] => Array
                (
                    [name] => University of Technology Sydney
                )

            [jobsboard] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Research Jobs
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [job] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 44144
                    [title] => Associate Lecturer - Clinical Exercise Physiology
                )

            [organisation] => Array
                (
                    [name] => James Cook University
                )

            [jobsboard] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Research Jobs
                )

        )
)
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xml needs a root node:

change:

```
$jobs = Xml::fromArray($jobs);
```

to:

```
$jobs = Xml::fromArray(array('jobs' => $jobs));
```